# How to add namespace attribute to ksoap envelope?

Tags: java, android, attributes, ksoap2, envelope

I need to add an attribute (xmlns:n0="urn:checkOTP") to the envelope generated by ksoap2 (Android version).

```
<v:Envelope
  xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
  xmlns:v="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <v:Header>
  ...
</v:Envelope>
```

Turn to

```
<v:Envelope
  xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
  xmlns:v="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
  xmlns:n0="urn:checkOTP">
  <v:Header>
   ...
  </v:Envelope>
```

the error code is:

```
W/System.err(858): Code: SOAP-ENV:Sender, Reason: Method 'checkOtp' not implemented: method name or namespace not recognized
```

The server is a gSOAP2 one, and work perfectly if "xmlns:n0="urn:checkOTP" is added in the header (tested with javascript).

Best regards.

Comment: You can specify Namespace when you create SoapObject. Constructor, as parameter, expects Namespace and MethodName. Try to do: "SoapObject request = new SoapObject("urn:checkOTP", "checkOTP")

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject("urn:checkOTP", "checkOTP")
```

That seems to add the namespace not to the envelope, but as an attribute to the method element inside the body element, but is also works however.